# Windows XP Timezone getting changed automatically on restart

Tags: windows-xp, reboot, time-zone

I am in Mauritius (GMT+4), and in 2008, the Government tested working with daylight saving changes in our country. A new timezone was created specifically for Mauritius. Since it was applicable for only that year (2008-2009), the next year we had to change back to the original timezone, Abu Dhabi/Muscat.

On this computer at work however, my timezone gets back to Mauritius every time I restart my PC. Even the IT Support can't seem to find the solution.

Of course, they have tried every possible solution found on the net, disabling the time services, resetting and all, but something seems to be strange on my PC:

- Let's say I change my timezone right now to Abu Dhabi/Muscat.
- I restart my PC.
- As soon as it logs on (but not fully loaded), I check the timezone and it's still Abu Dhabi/Muscat.
- I wait some time, for everything to load, and I check again; the timezone's changed to Mauritius.

So, is there a way to know what is changing the timezone, so that we may locate the root cause? Is there kind of a monitor for that?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the problem was with the domain itself; the network admin had to move me to a different OU.

The problem was caused by a global policy apparently conflicting with Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Argentina and the same thing happened here.  The government decided to do daylight saving one year, then canceled it two weeks before the next.  For me the fix was to find the KB windows update that added the new time zone information.

[This kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955839/en-us) mentions your the Mauritius zone.

It also looks like there is a registry key you can edit

```
Mauritius Standard Time (GMT+04:00) Port Louis  Mauritius Daylight Time Mauritius Standard Time Last Sunday in October at 02:00:00  Last Sunday in March at 02:00:00     TZI=hex: 10,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,c4,ff,ff,ff,00,00,03,00,00,00,05,00,02,00,
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0a,00,00,00,05,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however this KB seems to be needed when adding the timezone. But!! It still helped me find this one, which was related: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979306/en-us. I'll try it and let you know :D

Comment: huh.. still does not work; do you know any way I could detect what is changing it?